# Create new column in pandas that will get values depend on condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have two databses:
**Database one:**
one has data about name of observation and different measurments that were taken for each obseravtion , e.g:
[image]

and **database2** which contain the same name observations (but not all of them) and carbom measurment for each.

I want to do these steps:
- add empty column in database 1 
- if the name in databse2 is in databse 1 , I want to take the carbon value and add it to the new column.

if not, leave it empty.

I have tried to write something but it's really the beginning and I feel stuck :

```
NaN = np.nan
df['carbon'] = NaN


for i in df.loc['name']:
    if i in df_chemo.loc['sample name'] is in df.loc['name']:
```

I know it is just the beginning but I feel like I don't know how to write what I want.

My end goal: to add to databse 1 new column that will have values from database2 only if the names are match.

Comment: Your data is confusing. How can multiple same names (18B) have the same measurements? Are they at different times? If so, is there anything that distinguishes them?

Comment: they are same item and different time. but I still need to have the same value attached

Comment: Try the `merge` function below. It should work for your needs.

Comment: yes i'm trying but for some reason I still get error with the key (name/sample_name)

Comment: do `df_chemo.rename(columns={'sample_name':'name'})`

Comment: @gust the problem is that column with the names has different name in each database?

Comment: @gust still get the same keyerror

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210302/discussion-between-gust-and-reut).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is the `merge` method:

```py
df = df.merge(df_chemo, how='left', on='name')
```

Example:

```py
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'x':[1,2,1,4], 'y':[11,22,33,44]})
print(df1, end='\n ------------- \n')
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'x':[1,2,5,7], 'z':list('abcd')})
print(df2, end='\n ------------- \n')
print(df1.merge(df2, on='x', how='left'))
```

Output:

```
   x   y
0  1  11
1  2  22
2  1  33
3  4  44
 ------------- 
   x  z
0  1  a
1  2  b
2  5  c
3  7  d
 ------------- 
   x   y    z
0  1  11    a
1  2  22    b
2  1  33    a
3  4  44  NaN
```